# Need someone to clear this up

Tags: etymology, word-usage

If one is 'beyond reason to deal with' then wouldn't this mean that they are more than reasonable to deal with? In other words, I'm assuming to be 'beyond reason' or 'below reason' is the same thing, as either are not within reason, but when you put both together then you are reasonable.

If I'm less smart, then this could also mean that I am more smart, correct?

Albert Einstein said "Do not worry about your difficulties in Mathematics. I can assure you mine are still greater." I'm assuming this means he has a less(or more)of a problem comprehending mathematics than anyone else, as he loves it. So "your" means me, and me means "you"? Something like that? If someone could clear this stuff for me.

Comment: One question per post, please. How can you be more smart if you are less smart? Mine seems to mean "my difficulties". Can you edit your question with your research focusing on what you don't understand?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's all related to the same thing. I just added more examples.The reason I see "less" or "more" smart as the same thing is because either are not smart by itself.

Comment: This is kind of confusing. ["Why *extraordinary* means *special*?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/318817/50044) was a question I had seen earlier.

Answer (score 2):

> If one is 'beyond reason to deal with' then wouldn't this mean that
>   they are more than reasonable to deal with?

No, it means the person is beyond the point where it's possible to reason with them.  Perhaps they're in a hurry, or drunk, or in a fever of pain, etc.  "Below reason" is not used in English.

> If I'm less smart, then this could also mean that I am more smart, correct?

Incorrect, for the reasons already given.

> Albert Einstein said "Do not worry about your difficulties in Mathematics. I can assure you mine are still greater." I'm assuming this means he has a less(or more)of a problem comprehending mathematics than anyone else, as he loves it. So "your" means me, and me means "you"? Something like that?

No, that was his witty reply to students struggling with math -- older Einstein had set about solving more difficult math problems than face the average student, so his daily learning obstacles were more aggravating than theirs; and, in fact, as a student young Einstein actually did have all sorts of difficulties with math.

Comment: Of course that's how most people would see it, but I don't think it's very practical. "No, it means the person is beyond the point where it's possible to reason with them" how would this be any different from being not within reason? And to not be within reason, you would either have to be below or beyond reason because it's the same as being on an object, or under an object. But neither are being the object.

Comment: @Sya *Beyond* means *outside the acceptable limits of something*. The limits can be upper and lower. So *beyond reason* will include *above* and *below* reason.

Comment: Ah, so I have the right idea.

Comment: @Sya, "_beyond_" is a more abstract [prepostion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition)  than "_below_", as _below_ specifies a direction, _beyond_ does not; a distant object can be "above and beyond", "beyond the sea", "beyond the farthest star", etc.

Answer (score 0):

**beyond** means on the far side of, they have passed through a state of having capacity to **[reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reason)** and out the other side. The phrase acknowledges that the person has known a state of capacity to reason, English does have a concept of a person being 'beneath reason', but that would be a rarely used application for a person of restricted mental development who has never attained a state of capacity to reason. So neither the person who is **beyond reason**, nor the person beneath it is currently *in* a state of capacity to reason, but their conditions are not equal

On your 'less is more' argument: neither 'less' nor 'more' mean 'equal to'. But the fact that both can mean 'not equal to', does not denote that they have the same meaning. Neither 3 nor 5 = 4, but 3 does not equal 5.

Comment: Does reasonableness really denote the ability to reason?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter probably not. I'll edit.

Comment: I didn't mean to disagree with you. You can do as you like. I just thought it was interesting.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Not at all, it was a fair comment and as soon as I read my answer in that light I agreed with you. cheers